# Passing a ByteBuffer to jni for C code to do write operations in its memory addr

Tags: java, java-native-interface, bytebuffer

I'm writing bindings to a c library using JNI. I have the following method i need to call from Java

```
void finalize(uint8_t *out, size_t out_len)
```

what i have been doing is this:

```
JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL myjnicall
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass classObject, jlong hp, jint output_len)
  {

        jbyteArray retArray;
        uint8_t output[output_len];

        finalize(output, output_len);

        retArray = (*env)->NewByteArray(env, output_len);
        (*env)->SetByteArrayRegion(env, retArray, 0, output_len, (jbyte*)output);

        return retArray;
  }
```

this works fine with small outputs. but the library allows for extremely big outputs. What i want to do is this instead:

In java i have a bytebuffer like this

```
byteBuff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(outputLength);
byteBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
```

then i pass it to my native JNI call:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL myjnicall
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass classObject, jobject byteBuffer, jint output_len)
  {
        uint8_t *output = (uint8_t*) (*env)->GetDirectBufferAddress(env, byteBuffer);

        finalize(output, output_len); //populating the memory space

        return;
  }
```

This works. but i have the following questions:

- Is this safe?
- Is the GC in Java not going to get rid of it in the middle of operation?
- Do i need to something else in c?

Comment: You should check that `GetDirectBufferAddress` doesn't return `NULL`.

Comment: Yeah, i checked that from the java code

Comment: No, you should check the return value of  `GetDirectBufferAddress`. Also, it might be a good idea to reuse the ByteBuffers.

Comment: i reuse the same bytebuffer for all my jni calls. is that what you mean?

Comment: Yeah. Or at least one per Thread (stored in a ThreadLocal).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is safe, assuming that `finalize` does not write outside the range `[output, output + output_len[` and you do not share bytebuffers between threads. (as remarked by @Johannes Kuhn)

When you call a JNI function with a JVM object (your ByteBuffer), the calling code clearly has a reference to it, so it will not be garbage collected. On the native side you receive a local reference that is only valid for the duration of the JNI call, but you can convert that into a global reference if you want the object to survive the call.